# sudo fine, sudo ls not working (command not found)

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ls

On Ubuntu 13.04 running in EC2, all commands through `sudo` work fine except `ls`.  Here are some example commands to illustrate the issue:

```
ubuntu at host in ~
$ sudo ls
sudo: command: command not found

ubuntu at host in ~
 1 $ sudo which ls
/bin/ls

ubuntu at host in ~
$ sudo /bin/ls
bin  dotfiles  init  npm  tmp

ubuntu at host in ~
$ sudo pwd
/home/ubuntu

ubuntu at host in ~
$ sudo which pwd
/bin/pwd

ubuntu at host in ~
$ echo wtf
wtf
```

My dotfiles are here https://github.com/mike-spainhower/dotfiles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 40 of your .aliases is aliasing ls to a command called 'command'.  Your system can't find this program named 'command'.

You can tell from your first sample error: the first instance of the word 'command' is the system naming the program it failed to find.

Comment: Derp. Thank you for finding that.  I guess the question for me now is why access to command is not allowed via sudo.  It works as root and there is no indication in visudo nor /etc/sudoers.d that it's disallowed (ALL is used for commands)

Comment: `command` is a bash built-in, not a program per se.  You can see the same behavior with `sudo cd`.  In general, sudo against built-ins usually doesn't accomplish what you think it would.